# Plot function with different parameters' values

Tags: plotting

[image]

how can I plot couple plots for different theta in one graph with theta step of 0.05 and from 0 to 1,5?

Comment: Have you remark that in the rhs of the equation there is no x but unknown valued parameters v and tt. So you must fix this before anay thing

Comment: Oh sorry I already defined v and tt previously.

Comment: Post code, please. Not images of code.

Answer (score 4):

Since I must leave and I have no response, I set a very simple example:

```
f[x_,theta_] := Sin[x^2]/(2 - theta)
Plot[Thread[f[x, Range[0, 1.5`, 0.05]]], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Obviously, this question is a duplicate.